# Determine truth value: If $n^2$ is a multiple of 5, then $n$ is a multiple of 5.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, arithmetic

good day mathematicians of Math Stack Exchange, I have a bit of curiosity about this exercise that my teacher proposed in class today and says the following:
Determine truth value:
For all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $n^2$ is a multiple of 5, then n is a multiple of 5.
Thanks so much! Please give a proof or a counterexample.
Quote of the day:
"If you have to prove a theorem, do not rush. First of all, understand fully what the theorem says, try to see clearly what it means. Then check the theorem; it could be false. Examine the consequences, verify as many particular instances as are needed to convince yourself of the truth. When you have satisfied yourself that the theorem is true, you can start proving it."
George Pólya
1887-1985

Comment: Hint: remember that if $\,p\,$ is a prime and $\,p \mid a\,b\,$ then $\,p \mid a\,$ or $\,p \mid b\,$.

Comment: @Oromion: Alternatively, if you don't remember that, of if you never knew it in the first place, remember the law of unique factorization. How does the prime factorization of $n$ relate to the prime factorization of $n^2$? Answer this question without regard to the prime 5. Then you'll know the answer.

Comment: I rather like the cookie analogy: "Primes are to integers as raisins are to cookies.  However you break apart a cookie with a raisin in it, the raisin will either entirely be in the one half or the other.  In the same way, however you break apart an integer multiple of a prime as the product of two integers, the prime will either divide the one factor or the other."

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I understand.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ohh Interesting and funny. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be any integer.  Express $|y|=5q+r$. Where $r$ is the remainder of $|y|$ after division by $5$. And $q$ is the quotient.

Then,

$$y^2=|y|^2=(5q+r)^2=5q^2+10qr+r^2=5(q^2+2qr)+r^2$$

$$=5k+r^2$$

If we want $y^2$ to be divisible by $5$ then $y^2-5k=r^2$ needs to be divisible by $5$.

There are a couple possibilities for the remainder $r$, those being $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$. Only $r=0$ gives an $r^2$ divisible by $5$. So  we need $|y|=5q+0$ and hence $y=\pm 5q$.

Comment: Thank you. I will study your proof.

Comment: You're welcome.